# FFImageLoading xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I'm using FFImageLoading but the view where I call this SDK apparently does not show but is loading. Here is the StackTrace:

> 01-25 13:37:14.393 I/art     ( 9376): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>
> 01-25 13:37:14.394 I/art     ( 9376): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class
>
> 01-25 13:37:14.394 I/art     ( 9376): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Views.MisActivos.PhotoActivo"
             xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor = "White" Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                <Label x:Name="TxtAd" Text="" TextColor="White" FontSize="20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                <Button x:Name="btn" BackgroundColor="Gray" BorderColor="Gray" Text="X" FontSize="8" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" Clicked="Back_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Button>
             </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"> 
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                            WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
                            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                            Source = "Photo.jpg"
                            x:Name="PhotoImage">
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
             </StackLayout> 
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">
                <Button x:Name="CameraButton" Image="Photo1.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Button x:Name="BtnVerifica" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Gray" Image="Verificar.png" Clicked="BtnOk_Click" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="false"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I call it with this, `this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PhotoActivo(Activo, "ACT"));`, but does not show anything.

Comment: That is not a stack trace. You need to provide information about what you are doing. How does someone reproduce this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i hope this help to understand, the problem is in ffimageloading:CachedImage if i change that for image works fine

Comment: So you don't see any of the buttons or labels either?

Comment: no, in fact, it seems that I stay on the page from where I call her

Comment: Where do you call PushModalAsync?

Comment: in a button event